# How to improve this fluent interface?

Tags: c#

I am working on a fluent interface for exception handling.
Here's how it looks :

```
On<NullReferenceException>()
                    .First.LogTo("errors")
                    .Then.TranslateTo("null object");

            On<FileNotFoundException>()
                    .First.Translate(excpetion => excpetion.Message)
                    .Then.LogTo("errors");

            On<InvalidOperationException>()
                    .If(excpetion => excpetion.Message.Contains("This is a test"))
                    .First.DoSomethingElse(exception => Console.WriteLine(exception.Message));

            On<ArgumentException>().Ignore();
```

Do you think it's as fluent as it should be ? can I make it better ? any suggestions ?

Answer (score 7):

I would remove the First and Then methods and just execute actions in the order they are declared.

Comment: I wanted to show that it works in a first in first out flow.

Comment: +1 Assuming there is no distinction other than ordering I would resent having to type all that extra stuff simply to indicate it happens in order.

Comment: Indicating how consecutive commands are processed is a job for the documentation. I see where you were going with the idea but having those methods will only make the code base harder to maintain in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

```
On<InvalidOperationException>()
                .If(excpetion => excpetion.Message.Contains("This is a test"))
                .First.DoSomethingElse(exception => Console.WriteLine(exception.Message));
```

Is a bit confusing to me regarding scoping of the individual branch. If you want to do more than one thing after the if statement, how are you supposed to do it? I assume that your code will call the lambda in `DoSomethingElse()` if the condition is true. If that was followed by `.Then.LogTo("errors");`, would the execution of the `LogTo` also be conditional based on the `If`?

Perhaps, if you can make it clearer what is done in each specific case it would be easier to read this scoping. Say for instance,

```
On<InvalidOperationException>()
                .If(excpetion => excpetion.Message.Contains("This is a test"), whentrue => {
                   whentrue.SomethingElse(exception => Console.WriteLine(exception.Message))
                     .LogTo("console");
                },
                otherwise => otherwise.LogTo("eventLog");
```

Comment: maybe if is not a right keyword I would actually like to have a filter over Exception to response to some that satisfy this filter .Therefore there's no otherwise.There should be another policy for them

Comment: Even if you rename `If` to `Filter` you'd still have the same issue of it being unclear how many of the following statements are part of what's being done to the filtered exceptions. You'll need some sort of grouping structure to keep track of that. As you say, the `otherwise` part may be optional.